# UI state of activity not cleared when killing the activity while in background (on rooted phone)

Tags: android, process, android-activity

I need to delete the user data (username, password) of both the native Facebook app (com.facebook.katana) and the stock browser on Android (com.android.browser) on a rooted phone via command line (which I call from my own app).

This is what I'm calling:

```
rm /data/data/com.android.browser/cache/webviewCache/*
rm /data/data/com.android.browser/databases/*
killall -9 com.android.browser

rm /data/data/com.facebook.katana/cache/webviewCache/*
rm /data/data/com.facebook.katana/databases/*
killall -9 com.facebook.katana
```

**After I kill the facebook process, I check with ps and there is no FB process running anymore. I then restart FB via long-press on home and choosing the FB app. Previous username/password still show on the login screen (= same screen as I left it before I killed the app). When I then press 'back' on the device, and then start the app again via home long-press / select FB, the login screen is empty as it should. Where do the values for username/password come when I start FB again in the first place?**

I assume that the login activity still retrieves the `savedInstanceState`, but how could that be avoided - or else, where are those UI states actually stored, in order to delete them? But also, shouldn't the restarted app, after all it's processes are killed,  already be in a new lifecycle?

Same problem is with the stock browser: if i leave the browser and I'm on the login page of for example gmail.com where the username/password is entered (but form not submitted yet), then killing the browser process, the values (username) entered into the form will still be there after restarting the app again after it's been killed.

Comment: you can also see the thread on the Android developer group: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/990feed121f0ea39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/990feed121f0ea39:

reply from Dianne Hackborn:

> They don't have the same instance
>   state.  You can use "adb shell dumpsys
>   activity" to see the system's activity
>   stack; each of those entries is an 
>   "instance" of an activity as far as
>   the system is concerned.  Killing a
>   process while its UI is in the
>   background is a normal situation on 
>   the system -- it is what happens when
>   memory is low.  It is expected, and 
>   doesn't impact the instance that the
>   system has on the stack.  (It will
>   just  have to ask the app to re-create
>   it the next time the user visits it.) 
>   Killing a process while it is in the
>   foreground is not normal.  In that
>   case  the system didn't have time to
>   ask it to save its instance state, so
>   it can  not re-start the activity in
>   its last state, so it throws that
>   instance  away.
>
> Please leave the lifecycle
>   documentation.  Processes are just
>   transient  entities used to hold
>   running processes; killing a process
>   is not the same  as "stopping" an
>   application.  You are treating this
>   like a Unix system,  when it is not. 
>   Resetting an application back to its
>   initial state is done with the "clear 
>   data" button in manage applications,
>   which asks the package manager to
>   erase 
>   *all* of its data, and does a full force stop which in addition to
>   killing  processes also stops services
>   and tells all system services to
>   release any  state they have about the
>   app (such as configured app widgets
>   etc).  You should use the same API
>   that manage apps does for this, which
>   is not  part of the SDK, but you
>   clearly aren't trying to do something
>   in the SDK.   Which brings up -- your
>   question should be posted to a group
>   like  android-porting since you are
>   doing platform-level stuff.  Posting
>   questions  like this here is not going
>   to get a good response because when
>   people see  questions on this group
>   they are thinking in terms of the SDK,
>   which is not  at all relevant for you.which is not  at all relevant for you.